# How to handle app window's minimizing event in android (redmi note 6 pro)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, swipe

I use ionic 3 for my app and have an issue when test on android 8.
There is an event when user swipes in application from the right bottom corner to minimize it and swipes back (or stops swiping) to the initial position. Please check animated screenshot below:

[image: ioi]

I need to open keyboard when user cancels minimization, I am looking for an appropriate events, something like `onstartminimization` / `onendminimization` or `onwindowminimizestart` / `onwindowminimizeend` to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
pauseListener:any;
resumeListener:any;

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.pauseListener = this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {        
      console.log('**** MINIMIZE ****');
  });

  this.resumeListener = this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {      
      console.log('**** RESUME ****');
  });
});

ionViewWillUnload() {
    //remove listeners
    this.pauseListener.unsubscribe();
    this.resumeListener.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply Aviashai but it wouldn't work because pause / resume events are hiring only at minimization's final stage (when you push the window to the center).